# How can I get back the missing portions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, adobe-photoshop-elements

I used the Pen tool to cut out the picture from the background. When I refined the edges I forgot to refill these missing parts. Is there a way I can save them?

[image]

Comment: Assuming this is not the only section of the image that is missing stuff, you'd end up having to do more work compared to just redoing the whole selection. But you still have the original image, so you could make that visible, make a selection with the missing parts, duplicate to new layer and maybe after cleaning it up a bit, merge it with the cutout layer. It seems like redoing the whole selection and being more careful with the edge refining would be a better option. Also turn the selection into mask and it'll be easier to refine it manually later on.

Answer (score 1):

Find your original image and add it back to your Photoshop file. I see you have it on your background layer.

> Then enjoy using [LAYER MASKS](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) when you need to cutout something;
>   at least you can modify your selections whenever and however you want.
>   **You should really use layer masks.**

You will probably need to reselect the portion you cut out, add it to the layer mask and then adjust that layer mask to give a nose back to that poor woman.

Layer masks are like an extra layer attached to the layer you need to do some masking/cutout on; instead of literally erasing parts of the real image, you can specify on the layer mask what you don't want to see and hide it. You can keep working as you did but do this on the mask instead of the original picture. If you ever need to modify something, you can.

---

No, there aren't many other options; you could use your History panel and try to go back in the previous actions you did but you'll lose what you have done after as well. Or use the "cancel" until you get to that step. Or start over.